# Need help with the rename command in Linux

Tags: rename

I have several files with these names:

```
file1, A.ext  
file1, The.ext
```

I need to change there names as

```
A file1.ext  
The file1.ext
```

That is I need to move the article from the end to the beginning erasing the comma. How would I do that?

I have looked into rename command but I have no experience with perl regex, I came up with this ridiculous command which doesn't work, I'm leaving it for showing my hopelessness:

```
rename 's/(?<=[A-Z a-z \s]*),\sA//' *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have:

```
rename -n 's/^([^,]*),\s*(.*)\.ext$/$2 $1.ext/' *
```

- This `^([^,]*),` matches everything but a comma until a first comma seen from the begging of the files name.
- This `\s*(.*)\.ext$` matches zero-or-more whitespaces followed by anything and ends with `.ext`.
- The `$2` and `$1` is back-references to the `(.*)` and `([^,]*)` respectively.

will do rename as following:

```
rename(a single file,.ext,  a single file.ext)
rename(a single file, some thing.ext, some thing a single file.ext)
rename(file1, A.ext, A file1.ext)
rename(file1, the.ext, the file1.ext)
```

P,s: remove `-n` to do rename on files which is used for testing.

Comment: I came up with the following before seeing your answer: `rename 's/(\d\d)\s((\w|\s)*),\s(A|The)/\1 \4 \2/' *`